# Grass GIS: Store vector line attribute from raster layer

Tags: raster, grass-gis, attribute-table, line

I am using SRTM dem (**dem** raster) projected in UTM, for delineation of streams (**Canales**) in my area.
I used these grass gis extensions:

```
r.stream.extract --overwrite --verbose \
      elevation=dem  \
      threshold=1000   \
      stream_raster=Canales  \
      stream_vector=CanalesV   \
      direction=Direccion

r.stream.order stream_rast=Canales  \
     direction=Direccion  \
     strahler=strahler  \
     shreve=shreeve  \
     horton=horton   \
     topo=topo   \
     hack=hack
```

Now I need to see in the vector attribute table, for every single channel **CanalesV** its order already obtained in **horton** and other rasters too.

How can it be done in Grass GIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `r.stream.order` command should have the parameter `stream_vect=CanalesV`, instead of in the `r.stream.extract`.

Comment: that is right!  I added `stream_vect=CanalesV` to my code for `r.stream.order` and I have everything!  **Thank you!**

Comment: I'm glad to help